# how to reduce large image size to thumbnail size in android

Tags: android, android-image

in my app, i have large images, i display it in an image view by hard code the size as 60 X 60 dp. how to reduce the image size as image thumb nail size in android. is there programmatic way. because suppose i run my app in various resolution size design layout may get differ. my need is if i run my app in any resolution device image size should not get differ. how to do that in android. please help me.

i hard code image by the following code.

```
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/img" android:layout_width="60dp"
     android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most simple way is

```
int h = 48; // height in pixels
int w = 48; // width in pixels    
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(largeBitmap, h, w, true);
```

and detailed
This is called the image scaling

This will help you http://zerocredibility.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/android-bitmap-scaling/

Comment: Please Tell me Does this scaling reduce the file size too??  and after rescaling the image can we save it some where else in sdcard

Comment: this will truly reduce the file size but as we are not referring to SDCard, it will not be stored on that and in this case complete operation is done internal memory so complete benefit of reduced size will be availed by internal memory itself.

Answer (score 7):

Add the following elements in your xml file:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:layout_width="48dip" 
android:layout_height="48dip"
```