# android - fitting image in imageview

Tags: android, image, imageview

I'm implementing a widget where i'm trying to display a large image inside an image view (8mpx) like this :

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/widget"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_vertical|center_horizontal"


    >
<LinearLayout android:background="#ffffff" android:padding="1dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >
     <ImageView 
       android:adjustViewBounds="true"
       android:id="@+id/image"
       android:src="@drawable/sample"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_weight="1" 
       android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
       android:maxWidth="200dip"
       android:maxHeight="300dip"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the emulator everything seems ok, but when i deploy to device, i get the "problem loading widget" message.
the emulator is HVGA and my device has a 480x800 resolution.
Any ideea what am i doing wrong ?

Thank you!

==================================================

As advised by you guys i've made a screenshot of the logcat.
Here it is :

[image]

Comment: hi! yes, i want to display the full image resized (while keeping the aspect ratio)

Comment: Could you please edit your question with the full error output from logcat? Also, are you using hardware acceleration? If you are try turning it off and see what happens. I've tried loading very large images using hardware acceleration and there's a silent OpenGL error complaining there isn't enough memory to load the image, and this error only shows up in the logcat output.

Comment: yes the error in logcat seems to be memory-related...

Comment: this question sounds similar... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265008/how-to-reduce-large-image-size-to-thumbnail-size-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
imageview.setImageResource(your_image);
imageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
```

Comment: thanks! i tried it, but like this, i get the error message on both emulator and device

Comment: delete the android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
android:scaleType="fitXY"  in xml

Answer (score 7):

```
imageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```

Comment: thanks! i tried your ideea, but like this, i get the error message on both emulator and device

Answer (score 6):

Try below code

```
<ImageView 
   android:adjustViewBounds="true"
   android:id="@+id/image"
   android:src="@drawable/sample"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
   android:scaleType="centerInside"
   />
```

Comment: tried it! the above code gives me an error on both emulator and device. if i add the weight attribute to your xml it works on the emulator only, on the device not.

Comment: it's the same described in the question. instead of the widget i get a "Problem loading widget" message on the device screen

Answer (score 2):

Old post, but you never know...

The logcat shows the problem:

"allocation too large for this process"

The image you are trying to render is too large to fit into memory.  You need to scale the image down, but don't try to create a scaled version of the bitmap or you'll hit the same problem.  The solution is the load the Bitmap into memory but ONLY for it's dimensions, then create a new Bitmap with a sample size that reduces the overall size of the image.

Actually you don't even need to load in the image to get it's original size to do this but it often makes sense so you can choose an appropriate sample size.

e.g.

Assuming your Bitmap is obtained from an InputStream:

```java
InputStream in = ... // Your Bitmap Stream

// Decode JUST the dimensions
Options dimensionOptions = new Options();
dimensionOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, dimensionOptions);

// Get the dimensions of the raw
int rawWidth = dimensionOptions.outWidth;

// Choose a target width for the image (screen width would make sense)
int targetWidth = 480;

// Select the sample size which best matches our target size.
// This must be an int
float sampleSize = (float)rawWidth / (float)targetWidth;

// Assume lower, which will result in a larger image
int sample = (int) FloatMath.floor(sampleSize);

// Use this to decode the original image data
Options scaleOptions = new Options();
scaleOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // 4 bytes per pixel
scaleOptions.inSampleSize = sample;

// Now create a bitmap using the sample size
Bitmap scaled = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, scaleOptions);
```