# ANdroid: activity crashes even after reducing the image size

Tags: android, image, bitmapfactory

After many tries of reducing the image size, I could actually succeed; but still my app is failing to work after I try to view an image which I have shrink ed. Here is the code for that -

```
    package com.example.tg_db1;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.media.MediaRecorder;
    import android.media.ThumbnailUtils;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class add_company extends Activity{
        ImageView iv;
        Button b1,b2,b3;
        EditText et1, et2;
        RegistrationAdapter adapter;
        RegistrationOpenHelper helper;

        private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
        private String logopath;
        String imgPath = null;
        private Bitmap ThumbImage;

        //Adding for voice record
        ImageButton play,record,stop;
        private String voicerec=null;
        MediaPlayer mp;
        MediaRecorder mr;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.add_company);

            iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
            b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
            et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

            adapter = new RegistrationAdapter(this);
            iv.setImageDrawable(null);  //Should be blank before selecting the image

        }

        public void browse(View v){
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            int id = v.getId();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri imgUri = data.getData();
                logopath = getPath(imgUri);

                //code to check on large image display
                //start
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(logopath);
                int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
                int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
                String imageType = options.outMimeType;

                //iv.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(logopath,125,125));
                //end

                ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(logopath,125,125), 125, 125);
                iv.setImageBitmap(ThumbImage);

            }
        }

        //to display large image
        //start
        public static int calculateInSampleSize(
                BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

        public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) 
        {
            // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        }
        //end


        private String getPath(Uri uri) {
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int col_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(col_index);
        }

        private String imgFilePath() {
            File imgFile = null;
            try {
                imgFile = File.createTempFile("complogo", ".png");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            FileOutputStream fOut = null;
            try {
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(imgFile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ThumbImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
            imgPath = imgFile.getAbsolutePath();
            return imgPath;
        }

        public void reset(View v){
            et1.setText("");
            et2.setText("");
            iv.setImageDrawable(null);  //Image is removed when reset

        }
    }
```

and the resulting errors from LogCat -

```
    06-27 16:03:34.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4029): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-27 16:03:34.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4029): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { typ=image/jpeg }} to activity {com.example.tg_db1/com.example.tg_db1.add_company}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    06-27 16:03:34.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4029):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3103)
    06-27 16:03:34.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4029):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3146)
    06-27 16:03:34.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4029):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:126)
    06-27 16:03:34.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4029):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
    06-27 16:03:34.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4029):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    06-27 16:03:34.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4029):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    06-27 16:03:34.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4029):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4586)
    06-27 16:03:34.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4029):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-27 16:03:34.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4029):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    06-27 16:03:34.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4029):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    06-27 16:03:34.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4029):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    06-27 16:03:34.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4029):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-27 16:03:34.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4029): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    06-27 16:03:34.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4029):     at com.example.tg_db1.add_company.getPath(add_company.java:144)
    06-27 16:03:34.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4029):     at com.example.tg_db1.add_company.onActivityResult(add_company.java:79)
    06-27 16:03:34.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4029):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3099)
    06-27 16:03:34.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4029):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4839)
    06-27 16:03:34.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4029):     ... 11 more
    06-27 16:13:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(4537): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-27 16:13:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(4537): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent {  }} to activity {com.example.tg_db1/com.example.tg_db1.add_company}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    06-27 16:13:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(4537):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3103)
    06-27 16:13:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(4537):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3146)
    06-27 16:13:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(4537):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:126)
    06-27 16:13:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(4537):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
    06-27 16:13:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(4537):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    06-27 16:13:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(4537):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    06-27 16:13:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(4537):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4586)
    06-27 16:13:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(4537):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-27 16:13:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(4537):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    06-27 16:13:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(4537):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    06-27 16:13:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(4537):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    06-27 16:13:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(4537):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-27 16:13:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(4537): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    06-27 16:13:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(4537):     at com.example.tg_db1.add_company.getPath(add_company.java:145)
    06-27 16:13:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(4537):     at com.example.tg_db1.add_company.onActivityResult(add_company.java:80)
    06-27 16:13:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(4537):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4839)
    06-27 16:13:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(4537):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3099)
    06-27 16:13:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(4537):     ... 11 more
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your activity crashes not because of image size. you log cat showing an  `NullPointerException`

Comment: can you suggest me to resolve this error please?

Comment: Can you show which is your line no add_company.java:145

Comment: options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try another code and apply your projects..

Please see this link [reduce image size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265008/how-to-reduce-large-image-size-to-thumbnail-size-in-android)

Also another link..[this](http://zerocredibility.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/android-bitmap-scaling/)

please use this code ..

```
private void TakeGalleryImage() {

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String mFileName= getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage);
        SetImage(mFileName);

    } 

}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {

    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(UploadImageActivity.this, contentUri,
            proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    String mFileName = cursor.getString(column_index);

    return mFileName;

}
```

And set Bitmap in imageview

```
private void SetImage(String filename){

    if (!filename.equals("")) {

        File imgFile = new  File(filename);

        if(imgFile.exists()){

            Bitmap myBitmap = ShrinkBitmap(filename, 125, 125);
            mImgUploadImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            flag=true;
        }

    }

}
```

Here your reduce image code

```
private Bitmap ShrinkBitmap(String file, int width, int height){

 BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);

    int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight/(float)height);
    int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth/(float)width);

    if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1)
    {
     if (heightRatio > widthRatio)
     {
      bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
     } else {
      bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio; 
     }
    }

    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);
 return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: After u get images and convert to bitmap after apply this code see in link..thanks

Comment: I tried both ways. But still the result is same. Not getting the right output :-(

Comment: I get the image path and then using bitmap factory, decoding the image.

Comment: please use this link..but first you want to check bitmap is not null after apply this link..http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/06/reduce-bitmap-size-using.html

Comment: in above link set your image path in sdcard and try ...i hope so this is working 100%

Comment: I had tried this in my earlier trials. But it failed. May be something related to exceptions in not addressed well in my code

Comment: please use my edited code and this is working for my side..thanks

Comment: contants just as a string.. in this string file name store when u get image path..

Comment: This is working fine on emulator as such. But still some problem on device :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri imgUri = data.getData();
```

i think you are getting null in this line. Check whether imgUri is null or not.Like

```
if(imgUri==null){ 
  Log.d("Uri","uri is null");
}
```

Some device gives null for imgUri i don't know why?

Comment: I'm not getting it null. while I try to set the scaled image in a bitmap, I get that error